# Why does the pin constraints tool not list all views?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

In the screenshot below I selected the grey view and selected the pin tool.
Then if I want to create a constraint between it and the blue one beneath, then why isn't the blue view appearing as a neighbor?

[image]

Here's another example in a project just created in 30 seconds to recreate it, the top few views all appear and can be pinned but then the bottom few views aren't appearing.

[image]

Why is Xcode doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a test in my project. Drag the blue view little down so it don't  overlap the light grey view, then the blue view will appear as a neighbor in pin constraint tool.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode isn't showing the blue view in that list because the gray view's bottom edge is below (has a larger Y coordinate than) the blue view's top edge.

You can control-drag from the gray view to the blue view and choose “Vertical Spacing” instead.